# Firestore: Why can the operand here never be null and how should I handle no records being returned?

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I want to query a collection using a `WHERE` clause. There can either be 1 record returned or no records. I'm trying to handle the case where there are no records returned, but Android Studio is giving a warning pointing to my operand in my `if` statement saying that it can never be null. Why is this? And how would I handle potentially no records being found?

```
FirebaseFirestore firestore = FirebaseFirestore.instance;  

//Look up friendUID
final friendUserDocRef = await firestore.collection(usersCollection).where('username', isEqualTo: friendUsername).limit(1).get();
    
if (friendUserDocRef == null) { //The warning points here
  //...
}
```

Comment: Adding `limit(1)` doesn't make the API return a single DocumentReference.  The return value is always going to be a QuerySnapshot that contains 0 or more full document snapshots.  Your code needs to expect that and deal with unexpected cases.

Comment: @DougStevenson so then how how do I check for 0 returned document snapshots?

Comment: Have you looked at the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#execute_a_query)?

Comment: @DougStevenson yes, but what confused me was that the example in the docs goes right into iterating through each `docSnapshot in querySnapshot.docs`, as if it is assuming that there will definitely be at least 1 record. I want to check if there are 0 records and if so do something specific.

Comment: Just check the size of the returned array of documents before doing anything else with it.

Answer (score 0):

```
//Look up friendUID
final friendUserDocRef = await firestore.collection(usersCollection).where('username', isEqualTo: friendUsername).limit(1).get();
    
if (friendUserDocRef.docs.isNotEmpty) { //Clears the warning. Only executes if a doc was returned
  //...
}
```

A `QuerySnapshot` is always returned regardless of whether any documents are in Firebase - this is why it can't ever be null. Since you're using `limit(1)` in your case the `QuerySnapshot` will have either 0 or 1 items in the `docs` property of the snapshot. To check if know records are returns you'll check whether or not `docs` is empty.

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.